# C++: Why does this compile? (Handing this-Reference to base class)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, multiple-inheritance

I'm using multiple inheritance and one base class (`BaseBNeedsA`) needs access to another base class (`BaseA`). I know this could be solved cleaner with delegation, but it really would be a lot of forwarding code, and I have several similar classes like `BaseBNeedsA`.

In Visual Studio 2013 I could use `BaseA &` for access, in Visual Studio 2015 this seems to lead to object slicing or something. (Compiles, but the references are invalid). So I changed it to `BaseA * const` and everything works. However, while doing this I found something weird. The code below compiles in Visual Studio 2015, and I can not figure out why it should.

```
class BaseA
{ };


class BaseBNeedsA
{

public:

  BaseBNeedsA(BaseA *baseA)
  : _baseA(baseA)
  { }


private:

  BaseA * const _baseA;

};


class Derived : public BaseA, public BaseBNeedsA
{

public:

  Derived()
  : BaseA(),
    BaseBNeedsA(*this) // Why does this compile? Handing a BaseA&, but BaseA* required!
  { }

};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  Derived d;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: it calls a copy constructor of `BaseBNeedsA`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki That isn't a comment!

Comment: How did I miss this. Make it an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class `BaseBNeedsA` has an implicitly defined copy-constructor:

```
BaseBNeedsA(const BaseBNeedsA&);
```

which is picked by the call:

```
BaseBNeedsA(*this)
```

because `*this` in class `Derived` can be bound by a reference to `BaseBNeedsA`.

Comment: Thanks, totally missed it. I'll add C++11 deleted default implementations in all bases to get compiler errors for this nasty bug.